# In a WebSocket connection how to determine who is terminating socket first? Client or Server?

Tags: sockets, networking, websocket, server, tcp

I have opened a socket connection via Chrome console, which connects to my Java WebSocket server running locally - then closed it:

```
var webSocket = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:1234/support');
webSocket.close();
```

Here are the `tcpdump` logs:

```
masood@masood-ThinkPad-L450:~/Desktop/code/current/chat_server11$ sudo tcpdump -i lo port 1234
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on lo, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes


Socket Opening:
21:39:58.376375 IP6 ip6-localhost.34196 > ip6-localhost.1234: Flags [S], seq 969747395, win 65476, options [mss 65476,sackOK,TS val 3310041060 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
21:39:58.376393 IP6 ip6-localhost.1234 > ip6-localhost.34196: Flags [S.], seq 630365028, ack 969747396, win 65464, options [mss 65476,sackOK,TS val 3310041060 ecr 3310041060,nop,wscale 7], length 0
21:39:58.376410 IP6 ip6-localhost.34196 > ip6-localhost.1234: Flags [.], ack 1, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 3310041060 ecr 3310041060], length 0
21:39:58.378183 IP6 ip6-localhost.34196 > ip6-localhost.1234: Flags [P.], seq 1:535, ack 1, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 3310041062 ecr 3310041060], length 534
21:39:58.378197 IP6 ip6-localhost.1234 > ip6-localhost.34196: Flags [.], ack 535, win 508, options [nop,nop,TS val 3310041062 ecr 3310041062], length 0
21:39:58.398870 IP6 ip6-localhost.1234 > ip6-localhost.34196: Flags [P.], seq 1:130, ack 535, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 3310041083 ecr 3310041062], length 129
21:39:58.398890 IP6 ip6-localhost.34196 > ip6-localhost.1234: Flags [.], ack 130, win 511, options [nop,nop,TS val 3310041083 ecr 3310041083], length 0




Socket Closing:
21:40:08.678597 IP6 ip6-localhost.34196 > ip6-localhost.1234: Flags [P.], seq 535:541, ack 130, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 3310051362 ecr 3310041083], length 6
21:40:08.678618 IP6 ip6-localhost.1234 > ip6-localhost.34196: Flags [.], ack 541, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 3310051362 ecr 3310051362], length 0
21:40:08.679275 IP6 ip6-localhost.1234 > ip6-localhost.34196: Flags [P.], seq 130:132, ack 541, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 3310051363 ecr 3310051362], length 2
21:40:08.679293 IP6 ip6-localhost.34196 > ip6-localhost.1234: Flags [.], ack 132, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 3310051363 ecr 3310051363], length 0
21:40:08.679438 IP6 ip6-localhost.1234 > ip6-localhost.34196: Flags [F.], seq 132, ack 541, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 3310051363 ecr 3310051363], length 0
21:40:08.679487 IP6 ip6-localhost.34196 > ip6-localhost.1234: Flags [F.], seq 541, ack 133, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 3310051363 ecr 3310051363], length 0
21:40:08.679506 IP6 ip6-localhost.1234 > ip6-localhost.34196: Flags [.], ack 542, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 3310051363 ecr 3310051363], length 0
```

As we can see above that although it was client who initiated the `close()`, it was the  server sending FIN+ACK first without receiving FIN from client.I am confused.

1. How do I tell from `tcpdump` logs or any other logs that it was client who has called a close() connection?

I need to know this to ascertain if the problem is on client side or server side.

Comment: `WebSocket.close()` sends a WebSocket message which causes the peer to execute a TCP close.

Comment: You could decode the websocket messages

Comment: I already covered this in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72274575/): "*A client's `close()` asks the server to perform a TCP close, and a server's `close()` performs a TCP close immediately, so there is no way to know who calls `close()` first, unless the client and server are actively logging those calls. You are not going to be able to determine it from the TCP logs, since the initial `FIN` should always come from the server.*"